# Are capital gains tax-free in a Vanguard tax-free fund?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gain, vanguard, bond-funds

I own shares of the [Vanguard New York Long-Term Tax-Exempt Fund (Admiral Shares)(VNYUX)](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0576&FundIntExt=INT).

I'm wondering exactly what is tax-free about it.  The link says that the "interest income" is tax-free (reading carefully, it says that at least 80% of it will be tax-free, but in practice it has been close to 100%).  I assume this is what I see as dividends for the fund in my statements and transaction history on the website.

But how about capital gains?  In addition to the dividends/interest income, the share price fluctuates.  If I sell or exchange shares, will I have to pay capital gains (or take a capital loss)?

Comment: Are you a NY resident? Muni bonds are usually tax free in the State that issued them, but not in other states.

Comment: Yes I am - but good point, definitely worth adding here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, even though interest might be tax free, a capital gain or loss on sale of the fund is taxable.

Comment: So is any capital-gain _distribution(s)_ from the fund. Similar: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/45853/municipal-bond-fund-tax-risks/45862#45862